# Convert DataTable to SPListItemCollection

Tags: splistitemcollection, datatable

Consider the following code:-

```
SPListItemCollection collListItems = emp_info.GetItems(query);
dt = collListItems.GetDataTable();
```

Now i want to convert the dt object back to SPListItemCollection object

Is this possible in one of the following ways

1.)

```
SPListItemCollection collec1= dt as SPListItemCollection;
```

2.)

```
  SPListItemCollection collec1= (SPListItemCollection)dt;
```

If not is there any other way where i can convert DataTable object back to a SPListItemCollection object.

Anyone with any ideas, Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate through DataTable and fill into SPListitemCollection object.

Also check following link for the code details:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f772b759-28b7-4330-b4a2-ef7541f3e79c/how-to-convert-datatable-into-splistitemcollection

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned techniques would have only work if `DataTable` would have been derived from `SPListItemCollection`.

Since its not the case, so you will have to iterate over the rows in DataTable and will have to create list items for each row and associate it with appropriate properties.

Comment: But the datatable is derived from SPListItemCollection

Comment: Nope dude check `DataTable` class [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.datatable.aspx]. When you execute method `collListItems.GetDataTable();` it internally creates a new DataTable object and creates DataRow for all your listItems and add those rows into the DataTable. And this DataTable is returned as an object.

Comment: you can also check the details of SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Its basically a converter.

Comment: Hit the response as answer if that suffices you as answer.